# Xtra Grid Sorted Data on runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, xtragrid

I have a `xtragrid` on my form (let's say `myXtraGrid`)

And I bind a `datatable`:

```
myXtraGrid.DataSource = dtMyDataTable;

myXtraGrid.BestFitColumns();
```

Let's say I have just one `column` in `datatable` named `"My Column"` and it has three `rows` of data as below:

```
My Column
------
3
1
2
```

Than on `grid (on runtime)`, I click on `column header (My Column)` and sort the data

```
(3 1 2) ascending: (1 2 3)
```

My question is; how can I get the sorted data as a `Datatable` as below?

```
My Column
------
1
2
3
```

On `runtime` I must get the sorted data and process it.

Thanks friends.

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228449/how-to-get-the-xtragrid-filtered-and-sorted-datasource

Answer (score 0):

you can make a `DataView`.

```
myDataView dvMyView = new DataView(myDataTable);
```

This `DataView` can be sorted with:

```
dvMyView.Sort = " MyColumn ASC ";
```

So you have an sorted `DataView` which you can easily transform to a `DataTable` again:

```
myDataTable = dvMyView.toTable();
```

Now you have a sorted `DataSource` :-)

P.S In my opinion the BestPractice is to create an `objectlist (List<myClass>)`. This `Objectlist` can be sorted. And an further advantage is that values changed in the Grid directly change your object in the List!

I hope that was helpful.

Comment: It's okey but I do not want to sort data programmatically. On run time, I click on column header, sort all data and I want to get that sorted or grouped data. How can I do it?

Comment: You can run about all Rows in DataGridView with a Loop and Add them to a new DataTable (better is Objectlist!). Do this in the EndSorting Event from your DataGridView. So after you Sorting it will save the Datas in a DataTable/Objectlist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DefaultView` of `Datatable` and sort the view and later can be convert to table

```
if (dtMyDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
DataView dv = dtMyDataTable.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "cy_column ASC";
dtMyDataTable= dv.ToTable();
}
```

Comment: It's okey but I do not want to sort data programmatically. On run time, I click on column header, sort all data and I want to get that sorted or grouped data. How can I do it?

Comment: Not much familiar with xtragrid but you can refer to this link: http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/30556/