# How to get the sorted data from devexpress GridControl

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress, wpfdatagrid, gridcontrol

Suppose i sorted the gridcontrol from their fields, now i want to get the grid control all rows in a order it is sorted.I am able to get grid all records by using

```
(gridname.ItemsSource as ICollection).Count
```

but not able to get in the order it is sorted.

Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

**From**: [How to get the sorted data from gridcontrol](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q567701)

> To accomplish this task, you can enumerate all row handles and get
>   data by the [GridView.GetRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetRowtopic) method. Please refer to the
>   [Identifying Rows and Cards](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument642) help article to get additional
>   information about row handles.

Refer the below that may help to get sorted as accessing the filtered data:
[How to get a list of the data rows in a filtered grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2921)

[how to get the xtragrid filtered and sorted datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228449/how-to-get-the-xtragrid-filtered-and-sorted-datasource)

Answer (score 0):

1.Why you want to get the Sorted collection from the DataGrid when you can sort the Collection itself independent of the grid
For example You will be setting the

```
gridname.ItemSource = myCollection;
```

You can do orderby on this myCollection by using linq expressions which will give you a sorted list as you need.

2.Sorting from the grid and using that collection will have a performance impact as compared to sorting in a collection.