# Get filtered rows from devexpress gridview c#

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using devexpress `GridView` in my c# application. So I initialize my `GridView` like this:

```
gridControl.DataSource = new BindingList<ViewDomainClass.MaterialOffice.DAViewMTO>(_materialRepository.ViewMTOByDetail())
```

The output value of that is a `List<DAViewMTO>`. So my user is able to filter the data in `GridView` and I need just the data that my users filtered.

So I need to move these data (Filtered) to another list of type `List<DAViewMTO>`

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi @Ehsan, Please go through these ["xtragrid get filtered rows"](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=xtragrid%20get%20filtered%20rows) search results to get the reference from DevExpress threads asked on their forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
 public static List<T> GetFilteredData<T>(ColumnView view)
        {
            List<T> resp = new List<T>();
            for (int i = 0; i < view.DataRowCount; i++)
                resp.Add((T)view.GetRow(i));

            return resp;
        }
```

And call like this :

```
ColumnView View = gridControl.MainView as ColumnView;
    List<DAViewMTO> mydata= GetFilteredData<DAViewMTO>(View).ToList();
```

Comment: if needed, the namespace for the columnview is DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView

Answer (score 2):

You can use two approaches to get filtered rows from GridView.

1. The first one is to traverse through all visible rows from 0 to the GridView's [RowCount](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_RowCounttopic), get row handles from visible indices via the [GetVisibleRowHandle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetVisibleRowHandletopic) method, get the rows' underlying objects via the GetRow method, and insert these rows in a different IList.
2. The second approach is to use the GridView's DataController.GetAllFilteredAndSortedRows() method. This method returns IList of currently visible rows in the current sort order.

References:
[Getting Filtered Rows](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q303908)
[How to get filtered rows](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q337210)
[XtraGrid GridView : How to get the filtered rows](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q332604) - If datasource is datatable
[how to get the xtragrid filtered and sorted datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228449/how-to-get-the-xtragrid-filtered-and-sorted-datasource)

If you didn't find the way to implement this then go through documentation to get correct methods to fetch the data.

Hope this help..

Comment: In your reference i found this :https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q303908 but what is exactly ColumnView ?

Comment: [ColumnView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnViewtopic) is the base class of the GridView which generally create in Designer class if you drag-drop grid control.. there are different views for Grid Control so go through documentation to know more about these.. It is good that you found the answer.. :)